# Trying to create a program that encodes the numbers with strings

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program in Python that encodes the numbers with strings. For example, the program should take a command line argument like this "Call 753-293-1 Today" and produce an output like this "Call seven-five-three-two-nine-three-one Today"

So far I am unable to produce the expected result. My code so far encodes the numbers to strings but I do not know how to put the "-" to separate the string of  number. Please can anyone help me out here. Thanks

```
import argparse


# --------------------------------------------------
def get_args():
    """Get command-line arguments"""

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Jump The Five',
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument('text',
                        metavar='str',
                        help='Input text')

    parser.add_argument('-s','--strings',action='store_true',
                        help= 'Whether to encode numbers to string')

    return parser.parse_args()


# --------------------------------------------------
def main():
    """Make a jazz noise here"""

    args = get_args()
    text = args.text
    strings = args.strings

    jumper = {"1":"9","2":"8","3":"7","4":"6","5":"0","6":"4",
              "7":"3","8":"2","9":"1","0":"5",}


    number_to_string = {"1":"one","2":"two","3":"three","4":"four",
                        "5":"five","6":"six","7":"seven","8":"eight",
                        "9":"nine","0":"zero"}

    new_text = ""
    keys = ''
    num = ""

    for i in text:
        new_text +=  number_to_string.get(i,i)
    print(new_text)



# --------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do you understand what `new_text += number_to_string.get(i, i)` does? Specifically, what is the `+=` doing? Can you think about how you'd modify this line to add a hyphen before adding the word?

Comment: However, a better approach would be to create a list containing only the numbers translated to words, and then join that list on hyphens using `str.join` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not an elegant solution but it works:

```
def convert_numbers(string):
    number_to_string = {'1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'three', '4': 'four', '5': 'five',
                        '6': 'six', '7': 'seven', '8': 'eight', '9': 'nine', '0': 'zero'}

    is_last_number= False
    output = []
    for char in string:
        if char in number_to_string:
            if is_last_number:
                output.append('-')
            output.append(number_to_string[char])
            is_last_number= True
        else:
            output.append(char)
            is_last_number= False

    return ''.join(output)

string = 'Call 753-293-1 Today'
print(convert_numbers(string)) # Call seven-five-three-two-nine-three-one Today
```